# Make a SelectField select nothing by default

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, html-input

I have a `Form` containing a `SelectField`, something like this:

```
CHOICES = [
    ('A', 'Apple'),
    ('B', 'Ball'),
    ('C', 'Cat'),
]

class MyForm(Form):
    choice = SelectField(choices=CHOICES)
    # ...other fields here... #
```

When I render the form, it shows the SelectField with 'Apple' chosen by default. But I want to have nothing chosen in the beginning, so that the user is forced to make the choice themselves.

Is there a way to render a blank choice, which is displayed by default but is not a valid choice once the form is submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with the value `None` will display in the form but is still invalid when submitted. You can set it as the default option like this:

```
CHOICES = [
    (None, ''), # <-- This option is invalid when submitted
    ('A', 'Apple'),
    ('B', 'Ball'),
    ('C', 'Cat'),
]

class MyForm(Form):
    choice = SelectField(choices=CHOICES, default=None)
    # ...other fields here... #
```

Adding `default=None` to the SelectField is optional, since that's the default behaviour anyway.

You can also add a string to the value, like `(None, '--')` or `(None, 'Please select an option')`. That option will still be invalid.

**Note:** I suspect this behaviour is nothing to do with the None object itself, but happens because it gets coerced to `'None'` (type unicode) when submitted from the form and hence does not match the original `None` (type NoneType).

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why you author had `Apple` as default since default for `SelectField` is `None`. But there's another problem - it's not actually `None`, but `'None'` (as a string).

This strange behaviour discussed [here](https://github.com/wtforms/flask-wtf/issues/348) and [here](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/289) and seems like there's no solution.

My workaround is to use `__init__`:

```py
class MyForm(Form):
    choice = SelectField(choices=CHOICES)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        if self.choice.data == 'None':
            self.choice.data = None
```

```
>>> MyForm(choice='Apple').data
{'choice': 'Apple'}
>>> MyForm().data
{'choice': None}
```

Thought, it may be helpful for someone.